# How do I get the links in my nav to align beside other content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nav

I am still learning and could use some help with what I am sure is a painfully simple mistake in my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I am working on a website where the nav bar starts out as a small centered box with the company's logo, the word "Navigation" below it, and a small ">" arrow to the right of the logo.

When you mouseover the box, it expands to a wider rectangle, with an expanded logo to the far left. The word "Navigation" is still below it, but the arrow is gone. I accomplished both the logo swap and the hidden arrow using Dreamweaver's Behaviours panel. For the expanding nav box I used :hover.

Now, what I want is to have 4 Nav links appear when the box is expanded, which I again accomplished with Behaviours. The problem I am having is that the links are appearing below the box instead of inside of it. I have been searching online for hours and nothing I'm trying is working.

[Screenshots of what is happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOVzr.jpg)

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_showHideLayers() { //v9.0
  var i,p,v,obj,args=MM_showHideLayers.arguments;
  for (i=0; i<(args.length-2); i+=3) 
  with (document) if (getElementById && ((obj=getElementById(args[i]))!=null)) { v=args[i+2];
    if (obj.style) { obj=obj.style; v=(v=='show')?'visible':(v=='hide')?'hidden':v; }
    obj.visibility=v; }
}
function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
}
</script>
```

```css
Header {
 background-color: #525252;
 height: 110px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: -8px;
 text-align: center;
}
/*---------------------------Header End--------------------------*/


/*---------------------------NavBar Begin--------------------------*/
.Navbox {
 background-color: #BC1316;
 height: 105px;
 width: 100px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: -8px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 0px;
 text-align: left;
 
}

.Navbox:hover {
 width: 480px;
 text-align: left;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 0px;
}

.Nav {
 margin-top: 0;
}

#NavArrow {
 font-size: 18pt;
 float: right;
 margin-right: 8px;
 margin-top: 40px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
}

#Navlinks {
}

.navlink {
 display: inline;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<header>
  
  <nav>
   <div class="Navbox" onMouseOver="MM_showHideLayers('NavArrow','','hide');MM_swapImage('Image1','','img/ja-films-logo.gif',1);MM_showHideLayers('Navlinks','','show')" onMouseOut="MM_showHideLayers('NavArrow','','show');MM_swapImage('Image1','','img/ja-logo.gif',1);MM_showHideLayers('Navlinks','','hide')">
  <a href="index.html"><img src="img/ja-logo.gif" id="Image1"/></a>
  <p id="NavArrow">&#62;</p>
  <p class="Nav">Navigation</p>
   
    <ul id="Navlinks">
   <li class="navlink"><a href="#">About</a></li>
   <li class="navlink"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
   <li class="navlink"><a href="#">Current Projects</a></li>
   <li class="navlink"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
 </nav>
 </header>
```

[Edit: Here is what is happening now that I changed the display on .Nav and #Navlinks  to inline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZy1A.jpg)

Comment: So. Allot of what you are trying to do can be done with CSS and not involving any sort of JS.  Swap your logo from an img to a background css  and on hover replace one with the other or even using sprites.

Comment: When I tried doing it that way it would let me swap the images if the first image was directly hovered over, but what I need it to do is to swap the images when the whole nav bar is hovered over. Is there a way to do that with just CSS?

Comment: Yah. Thats easy.. Just use the nav element with a :hover ~ .child-element

Answer (score 0):

All that's needed is the following to solve that problem:

```
.Nav {
   margin-top: 0;
   display: inline;
}
#Navlinks {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
  margin-left: -40px ;
}
```

So that after the paragraph isn't block and that the list doesn't make room for bullet points, display on the same line as "Navigation" and come around to meet "Navigation".

Also if you wanted you could add `transition: width 1s ease;` to .Navbox for a smooth transition.

Comment: Thank you. That was very helpful.
However, now the "Navigation" and the Navlinks are all on the same line as the Image, instead of the line below it. Everything I've tried (margins, padding, changing the display to inline-block, etc.) just bumps the text over or back out of the box, instead of to the line below the image.

Comment: I added an updated image to the bottom of my post, with the result of your suggested changes.

Comment: that's probably because .NAV is inline. Removing that `display` from `.nav` should work. Not at a computer right now but once the paragraph with Navigation starts on a new line it should work. Sorry for the wait.

Comment: All that removing the .nav display does is push the links back below the nav bar.

Comment: Ok, I had a breakthrough! I removed the display from .nav and then changed the p display to inline, and suddenly the navlinks are falling in line with the "Navigation." Then I adjusted the margin-left on #Navlinks to get the spacing I wanted between them and the Navigation. It looks great now! Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You could put <br/> before the navigation paragraph - that gets it on the next line. But if you have it the way you wanted, I'm glad :D Still try the 
        `<p id="NavArrow">&#62;</p>`
        `<br/>`
 `<p class="Nav">Navigation</p>` and see if it looks better